# "Если обещал — ждите." или "Если обещал, ждите."

Tags: пунктуация

Когда между главным и подчинённым предложениями следует ставить тире, а когда запятую? Сама по себе конструкция "Если... то..." отражает причинно-следственную связь, что побуждает использовать тире. Однако также очень часто встречаются такие сложные предложения, написанные через запятую, что тоже вполне логично: одно — главное, другое — подчинённое, соединённое союзом если.

Где правда? Возможно ли, что различные знаки препинания здесь указывают на особенность интонации, с которой следует произносить эти предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно писать с запятой (с известными оговорками, перечисленными в источнике, который я как раз собираюсь процитировать).
Да, вы правы, это так называемые, столь ненавидимые многими в школе, интонационные знаки пунктуации.

[Цитируя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm) Розенталя:

> Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении
> При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные, реже
> условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут
> отделяться от него не запятой, а тире, например:
>
> - Буде спросит кто о чем – молчи... (Пушкин);
> - Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять (Гоголь);
> - Что она натура честная – это мне ясно... (Тургенев);

Когда ко мне пристают пунктуационные наци - я говорю им: "Отстаньте, это интонационное!" :)

Comment: Как-то непросто поймать эту интонационную разницу, ведь  в обоих случаях наблюдается восходяще-нисходящий переход от придаточного предложения к главному. Говоря математическим языком, здесь разница скорее количественная, нежели качественная, потому что чётко определить порог выраженности, за которым следует использовать тире, тяжело. Понимаю школьников. Хотя в случае бессоюзного сочленения уловить различие несколько легче. Просто мысли вслух.

Comment: @krokoziabla - интонационность в данном случае практически синоним смыслоразделения. Одно предложение как в большей степени обособляется от другого. Вообще говоря, это в большой степени субъективно. Другое дело что, например, лично я последний пример из цитаты не могу представить с запятой. Почему - сам не смогу толком ответить )

Comment: @shabbunc Вот и я. :-) Я по профессии математик-программист. Хотя я в последние годы испытываю нездоровый интерес к родному языку, мне бывает достаточно тяжело разобраться в наших нечётких и часто уповающих на субъективное отношение излагающего правилах употребления пунктуационных знаков.

Comment: @krokoziabla Чтобы подчеркнуть интонационную насыщенность, в случае с тире я бы поставил восклицательный знак: _«Если обещал — ждите!»._ Таким образом, можно передать некую раздраженность. В обычной спокойной речи, вариант с запятой, на мой взгляд, предпочтительнее.